# How to disable logging verbose in Hive JDBC

Tags: java, jdbc, hadoop, hive

Does anybody know how to disable logging or reduce the verbosity for the Hive JDBC driver?

I'm using hive-jdbc-0.8.1.jar and I'm also debugging remotely, thus, when querying a huge dataset, the logging to console messaging takes FOREVER.

I tried to set my log4java properties to only ERROR level:

```
   Properties log4jProperties = new Properties();
   log4jProperties.setProperty("log4j.rootLogger", "DEBUG, myConsoleAppender");
   log4jProperties.setProperty("log4j.appender.myConsoleAppender", "org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender");
   log4jProperties.setProperty("log4j.appender.myConsoleAppender.layout", "org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout");
   log4jProperties.setProperty("log4j.appender.myConsoleAppender.layout.ConversionPattern", "%-5p %c %x - %m%n");
   PropertyConfigurator.configure(log4jProperties);
   log.setLevel(Level.ERROR);
```

But hive jdbc seems to ignore these settings.

this guy on this [link](http://csgrad.blogspot.com.es/2011/01/how-to-avoid-excessive-logging-when.html) suggest some modification but he uses Jython, so I don't have a clue about how to replicate what he is doing...any clues?

Thanks.!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To do what [Dilip Joseph did in the link](http://csgrad.blogspot.com.es/2011/01/how-to-avoid-excessive-logging-when.html) you mentioned, here is what you would do in Java:

```
import org.apache.log4j.Level;
import org.apache.log4j.Logger;

public class Jdbc {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Logger rootLogger = Logger.getRootLogger();
        rootLogger.setLevel(Level.ERROR);

        // the rest of your code below ...
    }
}
```

If you are setting this up as a maven project, then be sure to [include log4j as a dependency](http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/log4j/log4j):

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>log4j</groupId>
    <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
    <version>1.2.17</version>
</dependency>
```